# How to do web scraping inside a page with infinite scroll?

Tags: php, python

How to deal with web scraping inside a page that has infinite scrolling feature?
As an example please take a look at the below page:
[This one](https://tehran.divar.ir/browse/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%84%D8%A7%DA%A9-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D9%85%D8%B3%DA%A9%D9%88%D9%86%DB%8C-(%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%D8%8C-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87%D8%8C-%D8%B2%D9%85%DB%8C%D9%86)-%D8%A2%D9%BE%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86/real-estate/residential-rent/apartment/?v02=0,1&v08=0,-100)
Is there any library which can do that?

Comment: I'd just hook into the api (ajax) request that fires off on scrolling and use the json data it responds with.

Comment: Inifinite scroll is implemented with javascript and ajax. Web scraping is typically done on the html returned in a regular http request, and client side javascript is not part of it. So if you can't get access to the ajax api that powers the infinite scroll, it's probably only possible to do web scraping using browser automation with selenium + phantomjs or something like that.